# laravel upload mp3 undefined variable

Tags: file, variables, audio, upload, laravel-5.4

An undefined variable error comes along while uploading MP3 files, other audio files works properly, and works perfectly with images, pdfs, and all the ordinary extensions!! this is kinda weird!!

If anyone could help out id be thankful..
and I don't think that the `mime type` is the problem, I have tried `audio\mp3` and `audio\mpeg` and lots more stated in the symphony common bug for mp3 mimes, but gives the same error.

Track Controller

```
protected function create(Request $r, $slug)
  {
      $album = Album::where('slug', $slug)->first();

      $artist = Artist::find($album->artist_id)->get();

$is = range(0,$r->ii);
foreach ($is as $i) {

  if($r->hasfile('file'.$i)){
    $file = $r->file('file'.$i);
    $filename = $album->id . $r['name'.$i] . "." . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $file = Storage::putFileAs( 'tracks', $r->file('file'.$i), $filename);
    $file = $filename;
    }

  $track[$i] = $album->tracks()->create(
    [
          'name' => $r['name'.$i],
          'slug' => $r['name'.$i],
          'album_id' => $album->id,
          'artist_id' => $album->artist_id,
          'track_pic' => $album->album_pic,
          'file' => $file,
          'release_date' => $album->release_date,
    ]);
}
    return  redirect('/album'.'/'.$album->slug);
  }
```

Create Track View

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ route('track.add', $slug) }}"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                                <table class="table table-hover" id="tab_logic">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr id='addr0'>
                                            <td width="70%">
                                            <input type="text" name='name0'  placeholder='Name' class="form-control"/>
                                            </td>
                                            <td width="30%">
                                            <center><label class="btn btn-default btn-round"><input type="file" name='file0' style="display:none"/><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></span></label></center>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                              <tr id='addr1'></tr>

                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                        <a id="add_row" class="btn btn-primary btn-round btn-icon pull-left"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a>
                      <a id='delete_row' class="btn btn-primary btn-round btn-icon pull-right"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></a>
                      {{-- Loop Counter before submit --}}
                      <input type="hidden" id="counter" name="ii" value="">
              <!-- Submit -->
                          <center>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                Add
                            </button>
                          </center>
              <!-- End Submit -->
                </form>
```

Comment: Which variable is undefined? is the log showing in which line is the error dispatched?

Comment: The Variable is `file` stated in line 72 in the TrackController
`Undefined variable: file` specifically while adding the file to the db through the create method `'file' => $file,`

`at HandleExceptions->handleError(8, 'Undefined variable: file', 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\tests\\laravel\\sys06\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\TrackController.php', 72, array('r' => object(Request), 'slug' => 'First Album', 'album' => object(Album), 'artist' => object(Collection), 'is' => array(0), 'i' => 0))
in TrackController.php (line 72)`